# Can't send ether in foundry test if I am the caller

Tags: foundry

I am testing sending ether to myself if certain conditions aren't met but I cannot do so as the methods I am using `call` and `send` are all returning false.

they work when send to another user but why I emulate that user the same error persists.

### edit

Turns out I needed to have either of these two contracts implemented.

```
    // Function to receive Ether. msg.data must be empty
    receive() external payable {}

    // Fallback function is called when msg.data is not empty
    fallback() external payable {}
```

Comment: Hey, can you please share the code to understand better the context?

Comment: @donoso.eth thanks. Turns out i needed to have the receive of fallback functions added in my contracts.